# fetch response returns undefined after deploying it to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern, netlify

I am trying to deploy a MERN stack app using Heroku for the backend, and Netlify for the frontend. After successfully building and deploying the site using Netlify, I encountered the error below when I tried to execute my Login fuction. I have been looking for solutions to similar problems and trying them out but to no avail.

error encountered

[image: 1]

I included some files that might be relevant to the issue below.

package.json

```
{
  "proxy": "https://netninja-workouts-app.herokuapp.com",
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

fetch function from frontend:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/user/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
}).then(r => console.log(r))
```

backend entry file:

```
// imports
const express = require('express'); // express
require('dotenv').config(); // fetch env variables
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // mongodb

const workoutRoutes = require('./routes/workouts')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')

// start up express app
const app = express()

// middleware - fires for every requests that comes in
app.use(express.json()) // looks for body in the data and attaches it to the request object to allow access to the request handlers

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method) // logs the request path and method

    next() // moves on to the next middleware
})

// reacting to requests - route handlers
app.use('/api/workouts', workoutRoutes)
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)

// DB Connection - ASYNC in nature (returns a PROMISE)
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        .then(() => {
            // only starts listening when database is connected
            app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
                console.log('Connected to DB and Listening on port', process.env.PORT);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

backend routing:

```
// imports 
const express = require('express')

const { loginUser, signupUser, getUserInfo } = require('../controllers/userController')

// express router object
const router = express.Router()

// route handlers
// get request (req, res) : request object has information about the request AND response object sends data back to the browser/client

// login route - POST
router.post('/login', loginUser)

// signup route - POST
router.post('/signup', signupUser)

// profile route - GET
router.get('/profile', getUserInfo)

// export router
module.exports = router
```

I greatly appreciate and welcome suggestions and help.

Comment: Please include your code in the post as a formatted code block rather than as an image

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the entire backend api url while using fetch .if u try to fetch data using `/api/user/login` it will append in your front end url like `https://your_frontend_url/api/user/login` which is not a valid backend api url

```js
const API_URL = "" //your api url deployed in heroku goes here

const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
}).then(r => console.log(r))
```

> If you are using heroku for free heroku has stopped their free tier last year, so verify that your api is working or go for alternatives like [render.com](https://render.com/), [railway.app](https://railway.app/) or [cyclic.sh](https://www.cyclic.sh/)